# How to fix cookies not sending to server due to same-site update of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

My chrome was upgraded to version **94.0.4606.61**, on previous versions of chrome I could just disable the same-site flags at `chrome://flags`, but right now on newer chrome versions, you cannot send cookies to a server hosted on a different domain, even sub domain.

I am working with my angular front-end locally, while using the test server, so in my host file I configured my local domain such as:

```
127.0.0.1    mysite-local.my-company.com
```

And the front-end is using the API at `mysite-test.my-company.com` which is hosted on the cloud.

Now when seeing the network tab, you can see that the cookies are not being sent because of chrome's new behavior with cookies due to security.

[image]

I could not find any solution for this besides downgrading my chrome version to **89**

How can you combine local and test/prod environments with this new challenge?

**Edit: Actually the issue here is that my local is HTTP and the API is HTTPS.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

Setting the requireSSL to `false` locally. Remember to apply the transformations through the environments.